# How to call default trait method?

Tags: rust

How can a `struct` implement a trait method but also call the default version of that method?

```
pub trait MyTrait {
    fn do_it(&self) {
        println!("I am doing it the default way.");
    }
}

pub struct MyStruct;

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn do_it(&self) {
        println!("Doing it my way.");
        //Call default method
        self.MyTrait::do_it(); //Not worky
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = MyStruct;

    m.do_it();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I saw that answer before posting. It is the same question. But the answer is more of a work around. Incidentally "It can not be done right now in Rust" will be a good answer to these questions.

Comment: Hi @RajV, what you're trying to do is reuse code through inheritance. Rust (and the community) has decided that this is generally not a good idea. The answer you saw is not a "work around" that's the idiomatic way to do this. You'll probably find this thread (https://users.rust-lang.org/t/oop-how-to-override/1980/4) helpful as well as the linked wikipedia article on composition over inheritance.

Comment: If you want a workaround then it might be prettier to add two separate methods to the trait. `pub trait MyTrait { fn do_it_default(&self) { ....}  fn do_it(&self){self.do_it_default() }}`

Comment: @nielsle yeah, that's the approach I finally went with.

Comment: Hi @Wesley, as I understand things, inheritance via composition applies to struct inheritance where data/state reuse is the goal. Reuse of trait methods is a slightly different topic. I have seen discussion (RFC 1210) about making it easier to reuse a default method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31462293/1036017

Comment: another nice approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311216/4247851