# Why don't we implement all the functions from Iterator to implement an iterator?

Tags: iterator, rust, traits

To implement an iterator in Rust, we only need to implement the `next` method, as explained [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/#implementing-iterator). However, the `Iterator` trait [has many more methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).

As far as I know, we need to implement all the methods of a trait. For instance, this does not compile ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bdb0e01739ffc17a271cdcc8eeb79424&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
struct SomeStruct {}

trait SomeTrait {
    fn foo(&self);
    fn bar(&self);
}

impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct {
    fn foo(&self) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The error is pretty clear:

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `bar`
 --> src/main.rs:8:1
  |
5 |     fn bar(&self);
  |     -------------- `bar` from trait
...
8 | impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `bar` in implementation
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because every method on `Iterator` except `next` has a [default implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html#default-implementations). These are methods implemented in the trait itself, and implementors of the trait gain them "for free":

```
struct SomeStruct {}

trait SomeTrait {
    fn foo(&self);

    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("default")
    }
}

impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct {
    fn foo(&self) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

You can tell if a trait method has a default implementation or not through [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html):

> #### Required methods
>
> ```
> fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
> ```
>
> #### Provided methods
>
> ```
> fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>)
> ```

Note that `size_hint` is in the "provided methods" section — that's the indication that there's a default implementation.

If you can implement the method in a more efficient way, you are welcome to do so, but note that it is [not possible to call the default implementation if you decide to override it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461902/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-default-method-implementation-of-a-trait-in-a-struct).

Specifically for `Iterator`, it's a great idea to implement `size_hint` if you can, as that can help optimize methods like `collect`.

Comment: Really nice! I was recently copy pasting some code and thought it would be nice to have a way to have a default implementation for methods. I just assumed this was not possible without inheritance.