# Reuse default method implementations in trait impls

Tags: rust, traits

In C++, an overridden virtual member function can call the version defined in its base class:

```cpp
struct foo {
  virtual void run() {
    printf("printf yeah!\n");
  }
};

struct bar : foo {
  void run() {
    foo::run();
    std::cout << "un-cout-h!" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

I want to do something similar in Rust. I have a trait containing default method definitions, and I want to reuse those definitions in impls where those methods are overridden:

```
trait Foo {
    fn run(&self) {
        // do something
    }
}

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn run(&self) {
        // call default implementation of Foo::run()
        // run custom logic
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

---

**Edit:** The proposed solution isn't completely satisfactory. Once I override a method, I intend the overridden implementation not to be usable by third parties.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311216/4247851

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't.

First of all, Rust doesn't have subclassing like C++ does.  `Foo::run` isn't a thing that exists in a way you can call it.  That method body is only used when you implement `Foo` for a type and *don't* provide an implementation of the `run` method.  It is effectively copy+pasted by the compiler into each `impl` where it is needed.

Secondly, the two examples aren't comparable because you've radically changed the meaning.  In the C++ case, you're defining an instance method.  In the Rust case, you're defining a *static* method.  Instance methods in Rust require an explicit `self` parameter.  Even if that weren't the case, though, it wouldn't change anything about the first point.

If you want to provide some common functionality, you need to write that somewhere else.  The simplest way to do this is to use a free function like so:

```
trait Foo {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        println!("Foo::run()");
    }
}

fn run_base(foo: &mut Foo) {
    println!("run_base()");
}

struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        run_base(self);
        println!("Bar::run()");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar;
    bar.run();
}
```

Comment: Oops, yes, I forgot to add `&self` parameters in my original question.