# Using associated functions in methods accepting trait objects

Tags: rust, traits

I'm working on a Rust trait, `LayoutSection`, and ran into an issue where I had to make two nearly identical functions for the trait: one that's an associated function and one thats a method: `section_type()` and `section_kind(&self)`.

Ideally, I would only have the `section_type()` associated function, however `LayoutSection` is unable to be made into a trait object unless `section_type()` has a `where Self: Sized` clause.

However I need to use `section_type()` in methods that use trait objects, so I was forced to create `section_kind(&self)`, which is exactly the same as `section_type()`, but it can be called on trait objects.

I know this is a horrible hack, and there has to be some alternative, but I can't think of any other way to do this.

Here is a simplified example of how these functions are defined and being used: (here's the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4a315d25251b47e3678ed242a0304b4b&version=stable&mode=debug))

```
fn main() {
    print_generic_info::<Header>(None);
}

fn print_generic_info<S: LayoutSection>(game: Option<Game>) {
    if let Some(s) = game {
        let section = s.get_section::<S>();
    }

    // The reason I wanted to use a type parameter in `Game::get_section`,
    // rather than pass a `SectionType`, is because I'm doing something 
    // like this later on:
    // let section = <S as LayoutSection>::with_offset(...);
}

struct Game;

impl Game {
    fn get_section<S: LayoutSection>(&self) -> Option<&LayoutSection> {
        Some(match <S as LayoutSection>::section_type() {
            SectionType::Header => unimplemented!(),
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum SectionType {
    Header
}

trait LayoutSection {
    fn section_kind(&self) -> SectionType;
    fn section_type() -> SectionType
    where
        Self: Sized;

    fn print_generic_info(&self) {
        println!("Type: {:?}", self.section_kind());
    }
}

struct Header;

impl LayoutSection for Header {
    fn section_kind(&self) -> SectionType {
        SectionType::Header
    }

    fn section_type() -> SectionType {
        SectionType::Header
    }
}
```

What would be a better alternative to this? I wanted to use an associated constant to store the `SectionType`, however using those still wouldn't allow `LayoutSection` to be used as a trait object. But something like that would be even better than the `section_type()` associated function.

Comment: Sounds good! Some other points to consider... *make two nearly identical functions for the trait* — the code shown doesn't have any implementation for either. *this prevents me from being able to use it* — without the error, it's difficult to tell what this means

Comment: Related Q&A that may be relevant: [Is it possible to extend a default method implementation of a trait in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31461902/155423), [Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438755/155423)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution using the `SectionType` enum, rather than using type parameters. I wanted to have an associated function called `SectionType::with_offset`, but I was able to add `SectionType::with_offset` a method to `SectionType` instead. Here is the updated example:

```
fn main() {
    print_generic_info(None, &SectionType::Header);
}

fn print_generic_info(game: Option<Game>, section_type: &SectionType) {
    if let Some(s) = game {
        let section = s.get_section(section_type);

        // Now I can do this:
        let other_section = section_type.with_offset(0);
    }
}

struct Game;

impl Game {
    fn get_section(&self, section_type: &SectionType) -> Option<&LayoutSection> {
        Some(match section_type {
            SectionType::Header => unimplemented!(),
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum SectionType {
    Header
}

impl SectionType {
    fn with_offset(&self, offset: u64) -> Box<LayoutSection> {
        match self {
            SectionType::Header => Box::new(Header),
        }
    }
}

trait LayoutSection {
    fn section_kind(&self) -> SectionType;

    fn print_generic_info(&self) {
        println!("Type: {:?}", self.section_kind());
    }
}

struct Header;

impl LayoutSection for Header {
    fn section_kind(&self) -> SectionType {
        SectionType::Header
    }
}
```

[Link to the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ef5e40e18f8e3ad8731b1c93d032aa42&version=stable&mode=debug)